# GPS Tracker for Android phones

Tags: gps, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, gps-tracking

Is it possible to track the GPS of Android Phone like Sony Ericsson Experia x10? This is what I want, I wanna know the location of Sony Ericsson Phone every time I misplace this phone,or I wanna detect the location of the carrier of this phone. How does it works?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Froyo or newer (2.2+) you can use SeekDroid ([Market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gtmedia.seekdroid)) or for lower versions the same company did Find My Phone ([Market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gtmedia.findMyPhone)). I've tested only SeekDroid, works great with the web interface, with Find My Phone you only get the GPS coordinates via text message, but you can input the coordinates to Google Maps for example.

Comment: I already have our own portal for the map, as of now we can track the location of the car which the gps was inside the car. By now I'm searching on how can I use the gps of Android phone which is Sony Ericsson Xperia X10i. Anyone who knows about this?

Comment: The apps I mentioned can do this, and you can find many more by searching the market for "GPS Tracker".

Answer (score 1):

I was using Google Maps Latitude (AFAIK shipped with stock Android) for that purpose.  Latitude is now integrated with [Google Maps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps).